# ExtJS Card Layout

Tags: layout, extjs

I used the card layout to switch between two created panels:

```
var config = {
layout: 'card',
region : 'center',
activeItem: 0,
defaults : {
//height : 160
},
items : [this.ePanel, this.dPanel]
};
Ext.apply(this, config);
```

The switching takes place based on criteria:

```
if(params.exchange==='ABCD'){
l.setActiveItem(this.ePanel.id);
} else {    
l.setActiveItem(this.dPanel.id);
}
```

As I switch between panels one of the panel contents get distorted. Are there any solutions to the problem? I am using ExtJS 2.2.

Answer (score 1):

I've never used Ext2, but I've encountered similar difficulties with Ext3. Here are two ideas you can try...

- Setting [`deferredRender`](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/2.3.0/#!/api/Ext.layout.CardLayout-cfg-deferredRender) to `true`.
- Calling [`doLayout`](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/2.3.0/#!/api/Ext.Container-method-doLayout) after `setActiveItem`, possibly after a small delay (because rendering is often deferred in Ext):

  ```
  l.setActiveItem(this.ePanel.id);
  setTimeout(function() {
      l.doLayout();
  }, 100); // more may be needed, one need to inspect Ext's code to know the precise value
  ```

  `doLayout` is often the solution to layout issues, but it also generally requires a serious amount of debugging in order to have it applied. In effect, layouts are cached (at least in Ext3), so your call can be ignored if Ext consider internally that nothing has changed. Furthermore, as I've already said, rendering is often deferred, so if you don't delay it enough, your `doLayout` call may be executed before the child elements have been rendered...